# How to add a Jersey REST webservice into embedded tomcat?

Tags: java, rest, tomcat, jersey

Basically I want to run some Rest classes in Tomcat 8 embedded.
I am unsure how to add them to the tomcat embedded instance I am creating.
So this is what I do.
Here is just that Jersey class:

```
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

import static javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType.*;

@Path("register")
public class RegisterRestAPI {

    private MerchantRegistrationService merchantRegistrationService;

public RegisterRestAPI(MerchantRegistrationService merchantRegistrationService) {
    this.merchantRegistrationService = merchantRegistrationService;
}

    @GET
    @Produces(TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String register() {
        return "Hello!!!!";
    }
}
```

And here is the class where I create Tomcat:

```
import org.apache.catalina.Context;
import org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException;
import org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat;
import org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig;
import org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.init.JerseyServletContainerInitializer;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import java.io.File;


public class TomcatServer {

private MerchantRegistrationService merchantRegistrationService;

public TomcatServer(MerchantRegistrationService merchantRegistrationService) 
{
    this.merchantRegistrationService = merchantRegistrationService;
}


public void start() throws ServletException, LifecycleException {
    String webappDirLocation = "restui/src/main/webapp/";
    Tomcat tomcat = new Tomcat();

    String webPort = System.getenv("PORT");
    if(webPort == null || webPort.isEmpty()) {
        webPort = "8080";
    }

    tomcat.setPort(Integer.valueOf(webPort));
    Context context = tomcat.addWebapp("/", new File(webappDirLocation).getAbsolutePath());

    tomcat.addServlet(context,"jersey-container-servlet",resourceConfig());
    context.addServletMapping("/register", "registration rest");

    tomcat.start();
    tomcat.getServer().await();
}

private ServletContainer resourceConfig() {
    return new ServletContainer(new ResourceConfig().register(new 
        RegisterRestAPI(merchantRegistrationService)));
    }
}
```

So as you see that is the part with the question marks is giving me trouble to create.
Also, just one lats question, this is the way I should add those classes to Run on server right?

**Update**
I added the line suggested by Michal Gajdos but at startup I get:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Servlet
>   mapping specifies an unknown servlet name registration rest   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.addServletMapping(StandardContext.java:3160)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.addServletMapping(StandardContext.java:3139)
>     at com.crypto.restui.TomcatServer.start(TomcatServer.java:44)   at
>   com.crypto.assembler.Boot.main(Boot.java:22)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)     at
>   com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120)

How should I call the servlet?

Comment: Thank you for this code sample. For some reason nowhere else on the web is this given. And yes I had the same issue that the answer below fixed, so double thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[ServletContainer](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/latest/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/servlet/ServletContainer.html) extends `HttpServlet` and can be passed to the underlying servlet container, simply create new instance:

```
new ServletContainer(new ResourceConfig(RegisterRestAPI.class));
```

You can also define servlet in `web.xml` and pass reference to this descriptor to Tomcat - similarly as done for Jetty [here](https://github.com/mgajdos/jersey-managed-jaxrs-client/blob/master/src/main/java/sk/dejavu/jersey/sample/heroku/Main.java#L32).

Comment: I did as you said in some way. 
So I added the servlet but what about the name? I am getting an exception about the name of the servlet? How should I call it?(See update above)

Comment: Try to change `registration rest` to `jersey-container-servlet` so that the name of the servlet and mapping reference to the servlet are the same.

Comment: Yes that was it. 
Thank you very much. I am a bit new with embeded containers I need to study a bit :) See you around!